# How to use tr command in linux to encrypt?

Tags: linux, encryption

I'm trying to figure out how to make the tr command encrypt characters from the space to the tilde (ASCII code 32-126). For example, if I enter a space in the command line, I want to see an exclamation point as my output since it adds one to the ASCII code. Any help would be much appreciated. I tried using

```
tr ' '-~ 32-126
```

but it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a rot13 encryption with

```
tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'
```

you can make an alias

```
alias rot13="tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'"
```

Exemple:

```
 echo "cinq" | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]' | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'
 cinq
```

Answer (score 0):

To translate whitespace to tilde:

```
tr ' ' '~'
```

To translate a range of ASCII (using the octal value):

```
tr '\rangeStart-\rangeEnd' '\newRangeStart-\newRangeEnd'
```

To add one to the ASCII value, shift the range by one:

```
tr '\040-\175' '\041-\176'
```

See [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) for details.

Comment: Ya I understand that but how do i get tr to do a range of letters. So from ' ' to '~' in ASCII code is 32-126. How can I use tr to make it so that their ASCII code gets added one.